# Applet won't run (Says not initialized)

Tags: java, applet

So basically, I've mentioned the HTML code in the java file, But um the applet wont execute for some reason, Help me

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
/*
<applet code = "demo.java" width=400 height=200>
<param name="txt" value ="Hey">
 </applet> 
*/

class demo extends Applet {
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        String string = getParameter("txt");
        g.drawString(string, 29, 40);
        start();
    }

}
```

Comment: What does the appletviewer say? Especially with Java console enabled?

Comment: Does `demo` class has any package statement?

Comment: How are you executing this `applet` via command prompt using `appletviewer` or via `HTML` file.?

Answer (score 1):

```html
<applet code = "demo.java" width=400 height=200>
<param name="txt" value ="Hey">
</applet>
```

That `code` parameter is incorrect.  It should be the fully qualified class name.  Or..

```html
<applet code = "demo" width=400 height=200>
<param name="txt" value ="Hey">
</applet>
```

To compile & launch it in applet viewer from the command line, do something like:

```
prompt> javac demo.java
prompt> appletviewer demo.java // (see Note)
```

**Note:** Yes I **do** mean the `.java` extension.  AppletViewer can launch an applet from that comment embedded in the source code.  See the [Applet info. page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/applet/info) (at **To compile and launch:**) for another example.

### Questions/Comments

#### Debugging

3. Ensure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show for applets & JWS apps.  If there is no output at the default level, raise it and try again.
4. Copy/paste all error & exception output the console provides.

#### Code

1. The applet code itself would be better to declare a `String txt` that is declared as a class attribute and initialized in the `init()` method, like this `txt = getParameter("txt");`.  the `paint(Graphics)` method might be called many times.
2. Any time a `paint(..)` method is overridden, it should immediately call `super.paint(..)` (for the BG color, if nothing else).

#### Questions

1. Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).
2. Why AWT rather than Swing?  See my answer on [Swing extras over AWT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6255978/418556) for many good reasons to abandon using AWT components.

Comment: *"AppletViewer can launch an applet from that comment embedded in the source code."* Whoa, cool! Also, nice answer.

Comment: @JasonC  *"Whoa, cool!"*  Yeah, I find it so handy I even have a shortcut for it in my editor. :)

Answer (score 0):

you should give the class name not java file name.Go through applet tutorials for good understanding.

Try this,

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;

public class demo extends Applet {

    public void run(){
        repaint();
    }   

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        String string = getParameter("txt");
        g.drawString(string, 29, 40);

    }
}

/*
<html>
<applet code = "demo.java" width=400 height=200>
<param name="txt" value ="Hey">
 </applet> 
</html>
*/
```

Comment: Still says, Not initialized.

Comment: @HarshilP Did you compile your source into a `.class` file? Did you create a separate HTML file? Because your example looks like you *didn't* compile your code and it also looks like you placed the HTML in a comment instead of in its own file. You should look at the tutorial I mentioned.

Comment: @JasonC *"Did you create a separate HTML file? Because your example looks like .. you placed the HTML in a comment instead of in its own file."*  That can work for applet viewer use.  See my answer for more details.